# ASP.net remove letters from textbox who got there from pasting (numbers only)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got an textbox who gets the input from a handscanner it works like a paste, some barcode includes faulty characters in the beginning ("]E0")

When this occurs the user must manually erase "]E0" from the textbox due to it is only accepting numbers (type = number)

Say textbox = "]E0733384833321"

user push next error numbers only comes up as a little dialogbox..

I want to remove the 3 first characters when this box appears..

Like this

```
If TextBox1.Text.Contains("E") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(0, 3)
End If
```

or

```
If TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("]") Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(0, 3)
End If
```

But I cant find anyway to do that, is it not possible? Any other solution?

The code is used by shops who scans barcodes with android-units (built in scanner) or from windows with usb-scanners.

Comment: _"But I cant find a way to do that, is it not possible?"_ You have done it already. What doesn't work?

Comment: the code looks fine to me. What is going wrong when you try that?

Comment: It is not executing the code after pushing the button, (the example and the rest) it stops with a little dialogbox "numbers only" only if it is numbers only the code will run.

Comment: @WTech: Have you used the debugger? What `TextBox1.Text` really contains? What means _" it stops with a little dialogbox "numbers only""_? Is that clientside validation? This question lacks a lot of necessary informations.

Comment: "<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" type="number" runat="server" Width="200px" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox>" I use type="number" because then the android-users gets a numbers only keypad when doing manually input (some products dont have scanable barcodes) if I remove type = "number" then the dialogbox "numbers only" does not appear

Comment: Maybe there is no way to run code when this dialogbox appears? I am no expert so thats why i asked, the dialogbox and the text is not created in my code, it comes from using type ="number" on the textbox

Comment: @WTech: Then the solution is to remove `type="number"`. That's a HTML5 attribute which prevents postback if you enter something that is not a number, but you want to allow that and fix it at server-side. You could also use a `CustomValidator` or `RegularExpressionValidator` that allows numbers and a number that has a prefix `]E`. Then you don' get a postback with invalid text.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ,okey thanks, then I will do that, cased closed, thanks to the rest of you who replied also

Comment: @WTech if your case is closed, please mark the question as answared. This is for the sake of other SO users searching to help unresolved problems, thanks.

Comment: I must be blind, where do I mark as answered?